# Google Charts, how can i set a calculated view in a ChartWrapper?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i use the ChartWrapper from google charts.. my actual implementation looks like this:

```
var dataTable=new google.visualization.DataTable(DATA);

var options = {
                 title: 'Name of the Chart',
                 vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
                 hAxis: {title: "Month"},

                 isStacked: false,

                 pointSize: 3
             }; 

var chartWrapperArgs = {
                     chartType: "LineChart",
                     dataTable: dataTable,
                     view: {"columns":[0,1,2]},
                     options: options,
                     containerId: "chart"]
                 }; 
var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
chartWrapper.draw();
```

the problem is, sometimes i must change the data type from "date" to "string" i do this in my old implementation(there is no ChartWrapper) like this:

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);

                dataView.setColumns([{
                    type: 'string',
                    label: dataView.getColumnLabel(0),
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                    }
                }, 1]);
```

this works and now i have tried the same with my ChartWrapper implementation but with no success:

i have tried this two approaches:

1.)
    var dataTable=new google.visualization.DataTable(DATA);

```
var chartWrapperArgs = {
                    chartType: "LineChart",
                    dataTable: dataTable,
                    view: {"columns":[
                    {
                        type: 'string',
                        label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(0),
                        calc: function (dt, row) {
                            return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                        }
                    },
                    1
                ]},

                    options: options,
                    containerId: "chart"]
                };
var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
```

and my second:

```
var dataTable=new google.visualization.DataTable(DATA);
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);

                dataView.setColumns([{
                    type: 'string',
                    label: dataView.getColumnLabel(0),
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                    }
                }, 1]);

                var ViewData= dataView.toJSON();


var chartWrapperArgs = {
                    chartType: "LineChart",
                    dataTable: dataTable,
                    view: ViewData,

                    options: options,
                    containerId: "chart"]
                };
var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
```

but this did also not worked..

what do i wrong ?

i know i can set the view directly to the dataTable like "dataTable : view" but i want only do this in the "view:" option or the chartWrapper.setView() option.. or is this not possible ?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle with your code?

Answer (score 2):

Your first method (setting the `view` parameter) should work, but your code had a syntax error at the end of the `containerId: "chart"]` line (the `]` should not be there):

```
var chartWrapperArgs = {
    chartType: "LineChart",
    dataTable: dataTable,
    view: {
        columns: [{
            type: 'string',
            label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(0),
            calc: function (dt, row) {
                return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
            }
        }, 1]
    },
    options: options,
    containerId: "chart"
};
var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
```

If that isn't working, can you post a full example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: It worked now i have used a wrong syntax, but thx for your help